# Launch a new process not as child process of the orginal process

Tags: java, linux, process, runtime

I want to launch a new Process by a Java Application with this code:

```
String cmdArray[] = new String[7];
cmdArray[0] = "java";
cmdArray[1] = "-Xms256M";
cmdArray[2] = "-Xmx256M";
cmdArray[3] = "-jar";
cmdArray[4] = "/home/HauptServer/Games/game1/cloud.jar";
cmdArray[5] = "-p";
cmdArray[6] = port+"";
Process pr = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmdArray, null, new File("/home/HauptServer/Games/game1"));
```

But the new Process is a child process of the original Process. How can I fix this (Java)?

Comment: Why do you care about child parent relationship? (BTW. I don't think this is possible, without killing the parent)

Comment: Because the child crashes very often

Comment: But if it is not a child it will crash also often, so what's the difference?

Comment: You can't. Under Linux, every process is a child of another process starting with `1 init`.

Comment: The problem is that I can run this command with SSH, then the server does not crash but if I start the process with a Java Process then it crashes sometimes